# v-checkbox with svg icon from local

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vuetify.js

How can I use the svg icons in my locale in the on-icon event of v-checkbox?

```js
v-checkbox.mx-0.mt-2.mb-md-16(color='#FF3C00' :on-icon="'../assets/ıcon/bell.svg'" :off-icon="'mdi-checkbox-blank-outline'" )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your class with svg background like this

```
.icon-checkbox-on {
   background-image: url(some-on.svg)
}
.icon-checkbox-off {
   background-image: url(some-off.svg)
}
```

And type this class into props

```
<v-checkbox
    off-icon="icon-checkbox-off"
    on-icon="icon-checkbox-on">
</v-checkbox>
```

It works for me.